# Reference for singular Jacobian being a necessary condition for bifurcation

Tags: reference-request, bifurcation

I am looking for a reference that state and prove that a bifurcation in a system $F(x, \mu) = 0$ can only appear if $\det(J) = 0$, where $J$ is the Jacobi matrix of $F$ with respect to $x$.

I looked at several books and lecture notes about bifurcation theory, and could find classification of bifurcations assuming it to be true, or mentionning it, but never a direct statement and proof. I assume it is considered textbook material in the field, but I can't find the relevant textbooks.

Also I can prove it myself using the implicit function theorem, but I would really appreciate a nice reference for it instead.

Comment: That statement is not true. For example, the Hopf bifurcation is a counterexample.